# Invalid value for key attachdbfilename C# Identity Server Connection String

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-config, identity

I am trying to create the identity tables in my server database. However, I keep getting an "Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'" error.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=den1.mssql.gear.host;Initial Catalog=groceryapp;User Id=appID;Password=password;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UsersDB.mdf;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="appID" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=den1.mssql.gear.host;initial catalog=groceryapp;user id=appID;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

I am following the tutorial of this video.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y02ccL4-_K4

**EDIT**

I changed the `|DataDirectory|` to my physical path, but now I get permission issues with SQL Server:

> ExceptionMessage=CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>   Cannot attach the file 'PHYSICAL_PATH\App_Data\UsersDB.mdf' as database 'testDatabase'.

Comment: can you post you code on how you are getting the `key`?

Comment: @JericCruz What key are you referring to?

Comment: is `|DataDirectory|` a placeholder?

Comment: No, that is part of the default connection provided by ASP identity

Comment: Ah, I see now, you can try to change that with the physical path of your Users.mdf

Comment: Okay, that solved my initial error.. However the new error is due to the permission issues of the server database. I think you solved this question though. Please leave your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JericCruz ALSO.. when I publish this to the live server, can I remove the attachDbFilename after the identity tables have been created?

Comment: @Mocha no, that is the repository of your database file. If you don't to have a file db, try to put it in a database instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

You can try to change that with the physical path of your `Users.mdf`

**Second:**

Try to check if user `appID` has a right create table. If not, give it privilege to create one.